# missing GWT examples from the backend

Tags: java, gwt, google-visualization, visualization

My goal is to create an interactive graph (visualization) from data that I have in my db. The data fetched from the db goes through some computation and then (ultimately) should be fw to a webpage with a GEO CHART. So imagine a google map where there're pins on the world and if you click on one of them you should see a dialog with a result that was initially computed in the backend.

To achieve this, I'm using GWT. [I managed to create a simple project](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted) and run in perfectly on my local computer.

Problem is that every time I'm reading something about google chart gallery it's always on the 'javascript' level and I'm looking for some code relating to the construction of the chart (say Geo Chart) from the backend level.

So my question is this: 
(1) Why a lot of the code from the backend level `implements EntryPoint` is deprecated and (2) where can I find up to date [examples on Chart Gallery](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery) created from the backend and not from a javascript (or am I missing here something in this process)

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you don't find such examples is, that the Google Charts API is *designed* to be used from the front-end. It comes with JavaScript classes which you are required to load: Depending on how you read the [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/terms/) ("Permitted Access"), accessing the API without these JavaScript classes might not even be allowed - in any case, Google may limit the number of requests you can make from a single IP, so it may not work well from the back-end anyway.

If you still want to attempt it (on your responsibility), you can try using a JavaScript engine on the back-end.

However, I would rather suggest to either use the Google Charts API from the front-end (as designed), or use a server-side charting library (e.g. JFreeChart) instead.

Comment: thanks @Chris Lercher I take it, from your reply, that I have to convert my result to a javascript?! Am I correct?

Comment: No, as long as you use it from the front-end, you can also use it via GWT Java code (which will be compiled automatically to JavaScript), see https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted